# getting event listener from checkboxes using if statement

Tags: java, swing

in my code i declare checkboxes and if one is checked present its content using combo box. 
the problem is if the user choose the first checkbox it display combobox (its resd the event) but if he choose anther one no action will perform.
here is the code of the event handler.

```
private static class HandlerClass implements ItemListener {
  @Override

  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
      GridBagConstraints cc = new GridBagConstraints();
      cc.insets= new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    String[] colums= { "year","version","author","ssn"};
     String[] colums2= { "ID","Name","Degree","Mobile","Email"};
     String[] colums3={"Author_ID","Fname","Lname"};
     String[] colums4={"Admin username","admin password"};
     String[] colums5={"catogery_ID","catogery_name"};
     String[] colums6={"Author_ID","ISBN"};
     String[] colums7={"student_ID","book_ISBN","copyno","end_Date","start_date"};
     String[] colums8={"Author_ID","Fname","Lname"};
 if(checkbox.isSelected()){
    for(int j=0; j<=colums.length;j++){
        String s=colums[j];
        cc.gridx=0;
        cc.gridy=1;
     combo.addItem(s);

     panel.add(combo,cc);}}
    else if(checkbox.isSelected()==false){
        combo.removeAllItems();
       panel.remove(combo);}


      if(checkbox2.isSelected()) 
    { for(int j=0; j<=colums2.length;j++){

     combo2.addItem(colums2[j]);
        cc.gridx=1;
        cc.gridy=1;
     panel.add(combo2,cc);}}
    else if(checkbox2.isSelected()==false){
        combo2.removeAllItems();
       panel.remove(combo2);}

     if( checkbox3.isSelected())
    {
       for(int j=0; j<=colums3.length;j++){
     combo3.addItem(colums3[j]);
        cc.gridx=2;
        cc.gridy=1;
     panel.add(combo3,cc);}}
    else if(checkbox3.isSelected()==false){
        combo3.removeAllItems();
       panel.remove(combo3);}

if( checkbox4.isSelected())
    {
       for(int j=0; j<=colums4.length;j++){
     combo4.addItem(colums4[j]);
        cc.gridx=3;
        cc.gridy=1;
     panel.add(combo4,cc);}}
    else if(checkbox4.isSelected()==false){
        combo4.removeAllItems();
       panel.remove(combo4);}

 if( checkbox5.isSelected())
    {
       for(int j=0; j<=colums5.length;j++){
     combo5.addItem(colums5[j]);
        cc.gridx=1;
        cc.gridy=1;
     panel1.add(combo5,cc);}}
    else if(checkbox5.isSelected()==false){
        combo5.removeAllItems();
       panel.remove(combo5);}

  if( checkbox6.isSelected())
    {
       for(int j=0; j<=colums6.length;j++){
           cc.gridx=2;
           cc.gridy=1;
     combo6.addItem(colums6[j]);
     panel1.add(combo6,cc);}}
    else if(checkbox6.isSelected()==false){
        combo6.removeAllItems();
       panel.remove(combo6);}

   if( checkbox7.isSelected())
    {
       for(int j=0; j<=colums7.length;j++){
     combo7.addItem(colums7[j]);
        cc.gridx=3;
        cc.gridy=1;
     panel1.add(combo7,cc);}}
    else if(checkbox7.isSelected()==false){
        combo7.removeAllItems();
       panel.remove(combo7);}

    if( checkbox8.isSelected())
    {
       for(int j=0; j<=colums8.length;j++){
     combo8.addItem(colums4[j]);
        cc.gridx=4;
        cc.gridy=1;
     panel1.add(combo8,cc);}}
    else if(checkbox8.isSelected()==false){
        combo8.removeAllItems();
       panel.remove(combo8);}

  }
  }
```

Comment: That is some repetetive code, maybe try using a method or some way to make the code better maintainable first? :)

Comment: you create your complete gui in an itemListener?

Comment: yes, i create the checkboxes based on number of array's content and add it to the form and if one of these checkboxes checked it will add a  combobox to the form for the checked checkbox